# Alterar o valor do atríbuto checked de um input type='radio'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho dois inputs radio

```
<input id="tab-1" type="radio" value="juridica" name="tab" class="sign-in"><label for="tab-1"class="tab">Jurídico</label>                                                                                 
<input id="tab-2" type="radio" value="fisica" name="tab" class="sign-up" checked="checked"><label for="tab-2"class="tab">Físico</label>
```

e quero fazer uma verificação para qual está selecionado, por padrão, o físico já está checked.

```
if ($("#tab-1").prop("checked")){
   document.getElementById('cpf').required = true;
   document.getElementById('nome-completo').required = true;
   document.getElementById('cnpj').required = false;
   document.getElementById('razao-social').required = false;
} else {
   document.getElementById('cpf').required = false;
   document.getElementById('nome-completo').required = false;
   document.getElementById('cnpj').required = true;
   document.getElementById('razao-social').required = true;
}
```

porém, não está funcionando. Quando eu seleciono o jurídico não funciona. Está funcionado apenas para o físico, que já vem pré-selecionado.

Comment: tente fazer `$("#tab-1").is(":checked")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este é um exemplo do código para você perceber o retorno de acordo com o click nos elementos inputs

```js
$(function(){
  $('input').on("click", function(){
 alert($("#tab-1").is(":checked"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="tab-1" type="radio" value="juridica" name="tab" class="sign-in"><label for="tab-1"class="tab">Jurídico</label>                                                                              
<input id="tab-2" type="radio" value="fisica" name="tab" class="sign-up" checked="checked"><label for="tab-2"class="tab">Físico</label>
```

Perceba que desta forma nos conseguimos obter o resultado boolianos do input.

HTML

```
<input id="tab-1" type="radio" value="juridica" name="tab" class="sign-in"><label for="tab-1"class="tab">Jurídico</label>                                                                              
<input id="tab-2" type="radio" value="fisica" name="tab" class="sign-up" checked="checked"><label for="tab-2"class="tab">Físico</label>
```

JQuery

```
if ($("#tab-1").is(":checked")){
   document.getElementById('cpf').required = true;
   document.getElementById('nome-completo').required = true;
   document.getElementById('cnpj').required = false;
   document.getElementById('razao-social').required = false;
} else {
   document.getElementById('cpf').required = false;
   document.getElementById('nome-completo').required = false;
   document.getElementById('cnpj').required = true;
   document.getElementById('razao-social').required = true;
}
```